# Print a postgresql table to standard output in python

Tags: python, postgresql, etl, psycopg2

I have a table in postgresql named mytable and I need to print the contents of this table from a python application to stdout.

I'm currently doing the following:

```
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=psswd")
        cur = conn.cursor() 
        cur.copy_to(sys.stdout,'mytable',sep = '\t')
```

However, I get some "\N" when its printed in between some columns. I believe the reason why this happens is because somewhere during the print process, the line exceeds and goes to the next line in the psql terminal and so these \N s show up.

Output:

```
E0307   1       M       400     Ethan   UTDallas        12.98580404     \N      50.79403657     1
E0307   1       M       400     Lucas   Baylor  15.18511175     \N      56.87285183     3
E0307   1       M       400     Jackson Baylor  13.64228411     \N      56.87285183     3
E0307   1       M       400     Jacob   Baylor  13.19878974     \N      56.87285183     3
E0307   1       M       400     Samuel  Baylor  14.84666623     \N      56.87285183     3
```

My question is the following:

1. How do I get rid of these \N in output? Is there an alternative way of printing a table? I'm trying to avoid ways in which I have to execute an entire "SELECT * FROM my_table" query. Something that just uses the name of the table to be printed.
2. Also, how do I get the table headers while printing out? I tried the following:

   cur.execute("COPY mytable TO STDOUT with csv header")

I get this error message:

```
ProgrammingError: can't execute COPY TO: use the copy_to() method instead
```

Also, I'm not sure if this is the best way. But something I tried to do :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

don't have a postgress table handy to test this but does this work for you?

```
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as psql

connection = pg.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=psswd")
#my_table   = pd.read_sql_table('table_name', connection)
my_table    = pd.read_sql('select * from my-table-name', connection)
another_attempt= psql.read_sql("SELECT * FROM my-table-name", connection)

print(my_table)

# OR
print(another_attempt)
```

Comment: I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-39-731d90653fa9>", line 1, in <module>
    my_table   = pd.read_sql_table('team_totals', connection)

  File "C:\Users\peshalnayak\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 351, in read_sql_table
    raise NotImplementedError("read_sql_table only supported for "

NotImplementedError: read_sql_table only supported for SQLAlchemy connectable.

Comment: ok I'll update my answer to use the read_sql function which takes a query

Comment: ok, hoping either the `my_table` or `another_attempt` lines work. one uses standard `pd_read_sql`, the second uses `pd.io.sql` which I found suggested specifically for connecting to postgres. curious which works, or if both do.

Answer (score 3):

That `\N` is the default textual representation of a `null` value. It can be changed with the [`null` parameter of `copy_to`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_to)

To have the headers in the output use [`copy_expert`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert)

```
copy = "copy mytable to stdout with csv header delimiter '\t' null 'NULL'"
cursor.copy_expert(copy, sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated earlier by Neto: `cur.copy_expert("sql statement", sys.stdout)` will work. To use `copy_to` you need to pass null param.

Try this if you choose the `copy_to` method (set null value - see docs). Print column names first.

```
header = [i[0] for i in cur.description
print header
cur.copy_to(sys.stdout, 'table', sep='\t', null='\N')
```